# What is the FindObjectOfType<ARRayCastManager> referencing?

Tags: azure-spatial-anchors

I'm reading the file "InputInteractionBase" from the samples, and there is this piece of code `arRaycastManager = FindObjectOfType<ARRaycastManager>();`. As I understand, AzureSpatialAnchors uses ARFoundation's ARRaycastManager to do raycasting, but I can't find this gameobject from the Unity scene?

I'm currently trying to get the detected planes, which should be from an ARPlaneManager but I can't find any references to it. How should I do this?

I think my main problem is that I don't fully understand how azure spatial anchors work with underlying platforms. If anyone could point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer:

In the CameraPicker object, it there is a XR Camera Picker script that chooses the correct framework, which includes ARFoundation prefab.

The prefab includes all the managers needed